# Is there a way to make thrown exceptions run first before anything else is executed?

Tags: java, exception

Here is the output of my code

```
    [Opening file and detecting number of duplicate serial numbers...]

--------- [Program terminated] Files having been saved and closed. -----------

        == Thank you for using Cargoship Info Correction == - File could not be found: 
noduplicate (No such file or directory)
```

As you can see, the very last part, "file could not be found: etc.." is oddly placed. It should be between Opening file and Program terminated, and in my code it is placed as such. However, when I run my code, it seems because exception handling are slower, so everytime I run my code, they may appear in different places instead of the right place.

Is there any way around this?

For the actual code if needed, here is the part:

```
System.out.println("\n\t[Opening file and detecting number of duplicate serial numbers...]\n");
        try {
            //counting number of objects in file
            int count = cargosCount(initialCargo);
            
            if(count <= 1) {
                System.out.println("\t[Terminating program - File \"" + initialCargo + "\" has no duplicated serial number, all is well!]\n");
            }
            else {
etc...
```

Then in the finally-clause of the try-block, I have the "terminated" message printed out.

**EDIT: Thanks for commenting, I found a way to fix it, had to print the error message in the same print as my own message:
`System.err.println("- File could not be found: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");`

**Re-EDIT: actually, problem still occurs in another way:

```
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.err.println("Please enter a valid input.");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("[IOException error] Stack Trace:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            System.out.print("--------- [Program terminated] Files having been saved and closed. -----------"
                    + "\n\n\t== Thank you for using Cargoship Info Correction ==");
            read.close();
        }
```

In this code, my InputMismatchException is printed after the finally-clause...

Comment: It is like your program outputs both to stdout and stderr and each get flushed in turn. Perhaps you can 1st) flush the stream (this is odd... I think println automatically flushes the streams), and 2nd) make sure no other process (beyond your terminal) is buffering your outputs and 3rd) make sure your terminal itself doesn't buffer them.

Comment: Please show how the error is printed.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `e.printStackTrace()` prints to the standard error stream (`System.err`), while your other messages are printed to the standard output stream (`System.out`). This is done by default to make it easier to route error messages to a different log file (for example) than regular output.

If you need regular messages and error messages to appear in sequence, you need to send them to the same output stream. You can do that by calling `System.err.println` for regular messages (NOT recommended) or by passing the standard output stream reference to the `printStackTrace` method.

```
e.printStackTrace(System.out);
```

Run the simplified example below, and note that the ArithmeticException error message is reliably printed after Message 2.

```
public class Printer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Message 1...");
        
        try {
            System.out.println("Message 2...");
            int x = 10 / 0;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
            System.out.println("Message 3...");
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("Message 4...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that it is not recommended to use ```System.err.println``` to print error messages I wrote myself?

Comment: Also, for my last edit, it is the InputMismatchException that is not appearing at the right place. In that catch clause I have no print stack. I only want to print out the message I wrote : ```System.err.println("Please enter a valid input.");```. In this case, should I "send it to standard output stream"? How do It do that?

Comment: @HelloWorld No, it's fine to use `System.err.println` to print error messages you wrote yourself. I just meant that I don't recommend using it to print regular (non-error) messages to get them in the same stream as errors. Better to put (hopefully fewer) error messages in the standard output stream, since it means fewer changes if you decide to separate them again for production code.

Comment: @HelloWorld Yes, if you want all messages to be in sequence, all of your print statements need to use the same print stream, so using `System.out` throughout your code will work.